# Firebase currentUser issue even when logged in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a situation where after the login redirect from a provider, the same code tells me the currentUser is null, even  though I'm seeing data in the network console. On top of it if I refresh it is good. But after the redirect, the user is still null.

I tried on auth().onAuthStateChanged but that doesn't work.

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `auth` but `auth()`, this should work:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if(user) {
        console.log(user.uid);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I did use auth() and it didn't work.